# angularjs ui-view does not replace with the partial jade template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular. I had tried to retrieve the name from input element and display it. I'm using express and ui-router.

1: I get no errors in my browser console, but the ui-router template does not show. So my first question is why templateUrl not rendered.

2: I get `<div id="mainApp" ui-view="" class="ng-scope"></div>` in my browser element, but there's no controller assigned to the template. So my second question is why ui-router controller (hello.client.controller.js) isn't being call.

Please give me some suggestions.

**app/views/index.jade**

```
doctype html
    html
        head
            title= title
            link(href='css/main.css', rel='stylesheet')
        body
            div#mainApp(ui-view='')

            script(type='text/javascript', src='/lib/angular/angular.min.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/modules/hello/hello.client.module.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/modules/hello/config/hello.client.routes.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/modules/hello/controllers/hello.client.controller.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/modules/hello/filters/hello.client.filter.js')
            script(type='text/javascript', src='/application.js')
```

**app/routes/partial.server.routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var partial = require('../controllers/partial.server.controller');
    app.get('/modules/:module/views/:partial', partial.render);
};
```

**app/controllers/partial.server.controller.js**

```
exports.render = function(req, res) {
    res.render('.' + req.path);
};
```

**public/modules/hello/config/hello.client.routes.js**

```
 angular.module('hello', ['ui-route'])
    .config(['$stateProvider',  function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('hello', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/modules/hello/views/hello.client.view.jade'
            });
    }
]);
```

**public/modules/hello/controllers/hello.client.controller.js**

```
angular.module('hello').controller('HelloController', 
    function($scope) {
        $scope.yourName = 'No Name';
    }   
);
```

**public/application.js**

```
var mainAppModuleName = 'Main'
var mainAppModule = angular.module(mainAppModuleName, ['ui.router', 'hello']);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#mainApp'), [mainAppModuleName], {
        strictDI: true
    });
});
```

**Project Structure**

- MyProject

  - app

    - controllers

      - index.server.controller.js
      - partial.server.controller.js
    - routes

      - index.server.routes.js
      - partial.server.routes.js
    - views

      - index.jade
  - config

    - express.js
  - public

    - lib

      - angular
      - angular-ui-router
    - modules

      - hello

        - config

          - hello.client.routes.js
        - controllers

          - hello.client.controller.js
        - filters

          - hello.client.filter.js
        - views

          - hello.client.view.jade
        - hello.client.module.js
      - application.js
  - server.js

Comment: Maybe the path that you put on templateUrl is not correct. Can you 'describe' your file structure?

Comment: @geo Thanks for replying, project structure added.

Comment: Test this on templateUrl : templateUrl: '../../public/modules/hello/views/hello.client.view.jade'

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. Browser element: <div id="mainApp" ui-view="" class="ng-scope"></div>, there's no controller assigned to the template.

Comment: This is another error

Comment: Thanks @geo :) I posted it as a second question